# How to mock _super() method in ember unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, qunit

I am writing Unit test for route. I have two route one is parent and other is child both contains model() function(hook).
When i am writing a child route test cases there is a call for parent model funvtion via this._super().i.e

```
model: function (model) {
....
        this._super(model);
}
```

Is there any way to mock this super(model function) in unit test to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. See Github issue below for more info.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12457